# Sort an array relative to element position in another array using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose I have two arrays:

```
arr1 = [64, 23, 35, 11, 55];
arr2 = [34, 10, 54, 12, 4];
```

If I rearrange (or sort) `arr1` then the elements of `arr2` should also be rearranged as per the position (or index) of `arr1`.

For example: if I sort `arr1`

```
arr1 = [11, 23, 35, 55, 64];
```

then the elements in `arr2` should be

```
arr2 : [12, 10, 54, 4, 34 ]  (arranged according to index of arr1).
```

Is it possible? I found that it can be done in same array but I am trying with two different arrays. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) You'll need to record the positions *before* sorting `arr1`. You'll also need to think about what to do with duplicates. Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: If the arrays need to parallel each other, they shouldn't be separate arrays. They should be a single array of objects.

Comment: Even though I think better data structures should prevent you having this problem in the first place I added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50370287/1641941) to the duplicate with the simplest option.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the original positions before sorting of the first array, then apply that to the second:

```
 // Wrap original positions and values:
 const withPos = arr1.map((v, i) => ({v, i}));
 // Sort
 withPos.sort((a, b) => a.v - b.v);
 // Unwrap & apply sort to second array:
 arr1 = withPos.map(e => e.v);
 arr2 = withPos.map(e => arr2[e.i]);
```

Comment: [Try it!](http://jsbin.com/cucopalusi/edit?console)

Comment: Thank you, I had been puzzled for a whole day thinking for it.